# need help to implement custom tooltip to textarea

Tags: java, swing

I want custom tooltip in textarea

Hello everyone i need custom tool where it will set color of text like first line as red second as yellow third as green.

within in single tooltip.

Please find code below

```
package org.example;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.*;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.*;

public class TextEditorDemo extends JFrame {

    public TextEditorDemo() throws IOException {

        JPanel cp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea(20, 60);
        textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
        textArea.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);
        RTextScrollPane sp = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);
        cp.add(sp);

        setContentPane(cp);
        setTitle("Text Editor Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.Theme theme = org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.Theme.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/org/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/themes/vs.xml"));
        theme.apply(textArea);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new TextEditorDemo().setVisible(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon me, but I am unfamiliar with [Java] classes `RSyntaxTextArea` and `RTextScrollPane`. Are they classes that you wrote?

Comment: What tooltip? I so no logic related toa tooltip. Why would the tooltip have 3 lines of text?

Comment: Hi @Abra RSyntaxTextArea and RTextScrollPane  are basically language syntax highlighter like java , csharp etc.

for info. https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea

Comment: Hi @camickr, I know I have not written any tooltips, but I'm asking how I can create my own tooltip with some GUI modifications. For the second question, I have some requirements according to my work; that's why I need separate colors for each line.